# php математические операции высокой точности

Tags: php, php7

При работе с числами на php вылазит проблема с точностью.
Например:

```
0.1 - 0.000023 = 0.09997700000000001
```

Пошарил по разным закаулкам интернета и везде предлагают разные решения:

```
round();
sprintf();
number_format();
и много других библиотек и функции
```

Собственно прошу совета, какой метод наиболее правильный и который будет всегда работать с максимальной точностью

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В документации по этому поводу есть отсылка к математическим вычисления произвольной точности:(в блоке "внимание") 
http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.float.php

Answer (score 4):

Советую использовать библиотеку [`BCMath`](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.bc.php) для вычисления высокой точности.

Например:

```
$a = 0.1;
$b = 0.00023;

echo bcsub($a, $b, 10);
```

Третий необязательный параметр используется для установки количества знаков после десятичного разделителя в результате.